# Expansion of the universe & laws of physics

Tags: space-expansion, physical-constants, laws-of-physics

Does the expansion of the universe have an effect on the laws of physics, or the constants used in physics? If we were to imagine the universe 40 billion years later, would the same laws still apply?

Comment: Lee Smolin thinks so; but to my mind if a law varies then we ought to look for a law underlying the variation; so philosophically speaking - no; pragmatically speaking - no, because we've not find any such law; philosophically speaking, again - possibly, if you're convinced by Smolins advocacy.

Comment: @MoziburUllah does Smolin say that there are universes within black holes?

Comment: @jjack: I can't recall the details; but something like that; the idea is to have universes give birth to others (with different physical laws) and then use some kind of selection rule that drives universes to something similar to ours.

Comment: @jjack: It's a highly speculative theory - but I don't recall Smolin using that phrase...;).